# Pass data to allocator

Tags: c++

I'm now beginning to learn how to write allocators and I want to write a simple allocator that uses a provided fixed-size pool of memory.

So far I have:

```
template<typename T>
class PtrAllocator : public BasicAllocator<T>
{
    private:
        T* ptr;

    public:
        typedef typename BasicAllocator<T>::pointer pointer;
        typedef typename BasicAllocator<T>::size_type size_type;
        typedef typename BasicAllocator<T>::value_type value_type;

        template<typename U>
        struct rebind {typedef PtrAllocator<U> other;};

        PtrAllocator(T* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}

        pointer allocate(size_type n, const void* hint = 0) {return static_cast<pointer>(&ptr[0]);}
        void deallocate(void* ptr, size_type n) {}
        size_type max_size() const {return 5000;}
};


int main()
{
    int* ptr = new int[5000];
    std::vector<int, PtrAllocator<int>> v(PtrAllocator<int>(ptr));
    v.reserve(100);

    delete[] ptr;
}
```

The above gives me the following error:

```
request for member 'reserve' in 'v', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<int, PtrAllocator<int> >(PtrAllocator<int>)'
```

I want to be able to somehow pass my `ptr` to my allocator so that `std::vector` uses that.

Any ideas how I can do this?

**EDIT: I solved it.** I had to use the following for `main`:

```
int main()
{
    int* ptr = new int[5000];
    PtrAllocator<int> alloc = PtrAllocator<int>(ptr); //declared on a separate line :l
    std::vector<int, PtrAllocator<int>> v(alloc);
    v.resize(100);

    delete[] ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a pointer, which will be dynamic in your case, as a template argument, which is static. You could pass a pointer if it were static, e.g. if you would use a globally allocated object.

What you can do is passing the pointer to `pool` as argument on construction as pointed out in [C++ allocators, specifically passing constructor arguments to objects allocated with boost::interprocess::cached_adaptive_pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595920/c-allocators-specifically-passing-constructor-arguments-to-objects-allocated):

> In C++0x, allocators should be able to call any constructor, not just the copy constructor [...]

**Edit** regarding your comment: The point is, an allocator allocates memory but does not initialize it. Thus you can only control e.g. memory placement or at least some basic initialization (setting 0 or whatever). To initialize memory an object has to be constructed. For this purpose you can implement `construct` which since C++11 accepts a range of arguments, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y19ftw27.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436499/instantiating-class-with-custom-allocator-in-shared-memory). Or you can use `new`/`delete` for construction and allocation as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201214/callling-object-constructor-destructor-with-a-custom-allocator).

Comment: Not all pointers are dynamic. You can pass an address of a global variable to a template.

Comment: Yes, but he did not wanted to create his pool globally. Sorry, should have pointed that more out. Made an edit.

Comment: I edited my post. I tried what you said. I cannot figure out how to pass anything to the allocator through `std::vector` construction.

Comment: I figured it out. I accepted your answer. It wasn't what I wanted but I added my findings to the OP.